# Приходит ли оповещение о комментарии, если его быстро удалить?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, уведомления

Может кто подскажет, я не видел упоминания в документации.

Допустим, я хочу написать какой-то комментарий участнику, чтобы он его увидел в уведомлениях, но хочу сразу и удалить комментарий — то нужно ли выжидать какое-то время после написания или уведомление о новом комментарии отправляется мгновенно после отправки комментария?

Я знаю, что у вопросов и ответов есть некоторый грейс-период, в течение которого правки сообщения не отображаются в истории правок; нет ли с комментариями аналогичного?

Типа такого:

- выжидается грейс-период, после момента, когда комментарий править нельзя — отправляется уведомление;
- если комментарий был удалён в течение грейс-периода, то уведомление не отправляется.

Если кто-то может ответить определённо — здорово, если нет — может проведём какой-то эксперимент? Я думаю, что обычно я удаляю комментарий [в течение двух секунд](https://habr.com/en/post/469189/) (если заранее планировал его удалить), можно проверить и другие интервалы типа минута, пять.

Comment: Можете мне под разными темами написать комментарии и удалить их после разного интервала времени. В самом комментарии напишите через сколько его удалите.

Comment: @АндрейNOP  Создал и удалил три комментария, причём последний содержал слово "версия 1", потом я заменил на "версия 2" и после этого уже удалил.

Comment: Не получил ни одного уведомления. Видимо, уведомление = ссылка на комментарий. Нет комментария – нет уведомления.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Это были комментарии удалённые на второй секунде и на тридцатой. Жаль...

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я вам ещё напишу комментариев, но ночью/ранним утром, чтобы гарантировать, что вы не прочитаете коммент, пока я сижу смотрю на таймер.

Comment: Я раньше так иногда делал, обычно люди удивлялись ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, уведомление к удалённому комментарию не приходит.

Но если написать и не удалять комментарий под удалённым сообщением, то уведомление придёт.

Насколько я помню, если удалить сообщение после написание комментария к нему, уведомление тоже должно быть, но я предпочитаю делать в другом порядке.